# Django: object needs to have a value for field "..." before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, many-to-many, models

I experience a strange error with Django 1.5:
I have defined a model like below:

```
class Company(models.Model): 
    user = models.OnetoOneField(User)
    agreed_to_terms = models.NullBooleanField(default=False) 
    address = models.CharField(_('Complete Address'), 
            max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True) 
    winning_bid = models.ForeignKey('Bid', 
            related_name='winning_bid', 
            blank = True, null = True)
    bid_list = models.ManyToManyField('Bid', 
            related_name='bids', 
            blank = True, null = True)
    ...

class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'), 
                            blank = True, null = True,)
    volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3,
            null=True, blank=True,)
    ...
    # all other attributes are of the Boolean, CharField or DecimalField type. No Foreignkeys, nor ManytoManyFields.
```

When I try to file the form with the initial data through the Django admin, I get the following error:
**Exception Value:

"" needs to have a value for field "company" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Please see the traceback below.
The error message does not make very much sense to me. The only m2m relationship is `bid_list`, which is `null = True` and was null at the time of saving. 
Is there something new in Django 1.5, which I have not discovered while reading the changelog (this is my first project in Django 1.5)?

Interestingly, when I save an object in the `Django shell`, I do not get an error message, but the object does not get saved without any error message.

```
In [1]: user = User.objects.get(username='admin') 
In [2]: new_company = Company() 
In [3]: new_company.user = user 
In [4]: new_company.save() Out[4]: <Company: Company object> 
In [5]: foo = Company.objects.all()
Out[5]: []
```

When I try to trace the SQL statements with the `debug toolbar`, I can only see SQL SELECT statements, no INSERT requests.

**What is the explanation for this strange behaviour?**

Traceback:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: /admin/company/company/add/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_extensions',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'registration',
 'south',
 'company',
 'bid',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1008.                 self.save_related(request, form, formsets, False)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_related
  762.         form.save_m2m()
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_m2m
  84.                 f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in save_form_data
  1336.         setattr(instance, self.attname, data)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __set__
  910.         manager = self.__get__(instance)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
  897.             through=self.field.rel.through,
File "/Users/neurix/Development/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __init__
  586.                                  (instance, source_field_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/company/company/add/
Exception Value: "<Company: Company object>" needs to have a value for field "company" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

settings.py

```
import os, os.path, sys
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

# Setting up folders
abspath = lambda *p: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*p))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TASK2_MODULE_PATH = abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps/')
sys.path.insert(0, TASK2_MODULE_PATH)

# Loading passwords
try:
    from settings_pwd import *
except ImportError:
    pass
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profile.UserProfile'
#ALLOWED_HOSTS = [''] # not needed for DEBUG = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-uk'
LANGUAGES = [
        ("en", u"English"),
        ]
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "media")
else:
    MEDIA_ROOT = "folder_to_upload_files"
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
else:
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/uploads/"
if DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media","static")
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = "folder_to_static_files" 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "assets"),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
SECRET_KEY = '...'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'task2.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'task2.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates/pages"),)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    # third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_extensions',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'registration',
    'south',

    # task2 apps
    'profile',
    'company',
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

log = DEBUG 

if log:
    LOGGING = { 
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'formatters': {
            'simple': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
                },  
            },  
        'handlers': {
            'console':{
                'level':'DEBUG',
                'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'simple'
                },  
            },  
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                },  
            }   
        }    
####################
# THIRD PARTY SETUPS

# For Crispy Forms
CRISPY_FAIL_SILENTLY = not DEBUG
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'

## For Django Registration
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7

# for Django testing to avoid conflicts with South migrations
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False

# Debug_toolbar settings
if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
        'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
        #'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CacheDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }

# Easy_Thumbnail setup
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '': {
        'thumbnail': {'size': (50, 50), 'crop': True},
    },
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `company` field on this model `Company`?

Comment: Exception Value: "<Company: Company object>" needs to have a value for field "company" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

You model does not have field "company". Is there everything ok in admin.py ?

Comment: @Hellpain I thought so too, but the admin.py could not be simpler: `from company.models import Company admin.site.register(Company)`. It is also strange, that the objects do not get saved in the `django shelll` without an error. very strange.

Comment: @akshar raaj I just checked again and the model does not contain a company field. Could there be another reason?

Comment: Show your 'Bid' model and settings.py please. Your model 'Company' is ok, problem is somewhere in another place.

Comment: @Hellpain I have added the settings.py and the bid class to the question. The bid class is very simple, only contains one ForeignKey and the rest of the attributes are Boolean, CharField or DecimalFields. Furthermore, the settings.py is barely altered. admin.py is also very simple. I am running out of ideas. Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using custom user model AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profile.UserProfile', but in code I suppose you use native django user.

I suppose your models should be like

```
class Company(models.Model): 
    user = models.OnetoOneField('profile.UserProfile')
...
```

read more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error disappeared by switching the User classes as you suggested. However, even so the admin page is returning that the object was saved successfully, the table is empty and no object reaches the DB. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It`s strange. Are you using postgre? There are several extra configs for postgre. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/databases/#postgresql-connection-settings
Else try to run project on sqlite. We must see where problem - in database or in code

Comment: Thank you for the hint to switch to sqlite. it revealed that the problem must be with the code, since the error persists (i actually see the original error message again).

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. The problem is solved. The devil was sitting in the save() method, which I overrode and forgot to copy in the post. However, your hints made me read the 1.5 documentation again, which revealed interesting news. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 12):

The problem has to do with how you use your views.
I think you are using:
`instance.add(many_to_many_instance)`
before you have an instance id.

so first save your model:

```
instance.save()
instance.add(many_to_many_instance)
```

Comment: Yes, the error message was complain about to access a non-existing database object. I vote for you.

Comment: I was having the same problem and your answer inspired me to look at other uses of many-to-many fields in my model class. In my case, the problem was a reference to a many-to-many field in `clean`.